# Getting error in uploading file in php

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to create a upload form through which the user can enter certain details(including a file upload) and then it will be inserted into a database, the row is entered successfully but I get this error. i.e 
**Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/computer/SIGN 001.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\stockm.php on line 28**
                            &
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2CEE.tmp' to 'upload/computer/SIGN 001.jpg' in C:\wamp\www\stockm.php on line 28

this is the code which has the entire scripting for the upload file portion.

```
$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
  $type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
  $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $pathAndName = "upload/computer/".$name;
  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pathAndName);
```

I have created a folder in C:/wamp/upload named computer where I want the image to be sent, in the database I get this location but in upload/computer there is no file, the folder is empty.

Comment: You are in `www` and are trying to upload to `/wamp/www/upload` which probably does not exist. Use an absolute path for the target path as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path `$pathAndName = "upload/computer/".$name;` is a relative path, thus it will search from the current directory of the executing script.

For example, if you are running from `wamp\www\test\upload.php` it will search for `wamp\www\test\upload\computer\` path.

You can assign the path from the root directory as `"/upload/computer/".$name;`, this will search for `wamp\www\upload\computer` path.

Further more, you have to check if the folder exist in the path and it has permission to access it or read it.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet for uploading file

```
$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$pathAndName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."upload/computer/".$name;
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pathAndName);
```

In above code snippet I have specified absolute path for destination path where the file  needs to be uploaded

Comment: thanks a lot, but if I assign this value in $pathandname then its still searching for directory in www, but the folder upload is in the folder wamp, how to set directory for that.